# Change position of Drupal ajax progress throbber

Tags: 7, ajax

When you are using views built in ajax pager. When you click on any element of the pager ajax throbber appears next to the clicked button. Can i change the location of the throbber, for example outside of pager div?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by overriding the CSS in your theme CSS file. Here is the class to use for changing the position of ajax throbber:

> .ajax-progress .throbber

You can set the position to whatever you want.

Also have a look at this blog: http://www.antimath.info/css/change-throbber-in-drupal-7/