# How to remove the extra loading icon in my custom Drupal form?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have created a custom form using (Drupal form API). It has email field as autocomplete.

```
//implements hook_menu
function mymodule_hook_menu() {

$items['add-form'] = array(
                'title' => 'Submit request to add chapter.',
                'description' => 'Submit request to add chapter.',
                'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
                'page arguments' => array(
                        'my_form'
                ) ,
                'access callback' => TRUE,
        );

$items['my/email/autocomplete'] = array(
                'page callback' => '_my_email_autocomplete',
                'access callback' => TRUE,
                'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
        );
        return $items;
}


function my_form($form, &$form_submit)
{
        $form['email'] = array(
                '#title' => 'email',
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#required' => TRUE,
                '#size' => 50,
                '#description' => t('Enter your valid email'),
                '#autocomplete_path' => 'my/email/autocomplete',
                '#attributes' => array(
                       'placeholder' => t('example@example.com')
                )
        );
        $form['submit'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => 'Submit'
        );
        return $form;
}


function _my_email_autocomplete($string) {

  $matches = array();
  // Some fantasy DB table which holds cities
  $query = db_select('my_table', 'a');

  // Select rows that match the string
  $return = $query
    ->fields('a', array('email'))
    ->condition('a.email', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->range(0, 10)
    ->execute();

  // add matches to $matches  
  foreach ($return as $row) {
    $matches[$row->email] = check_plain($row->email);
  }
  // return for JS
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

For some reason there are two loading icon in the email field, as shown in the screenprint below:

[image]

The upper icon is the default one, which seems to work fine but the icon below the default one continues spinning for no reason.

I tried clearing cache but not able to remove this.

Any suggestions about how to get this remmoved?

Comment: It's a css issue.. Reduce the height of the text field or adjust autocomplete icons..

Comment: Take a look at this issue queue to get an idea how to adjust css in your css file https://drupal.org/node/835694

Comment: is it the same issue in my site, I am on Drupal 7 and I am using custom omega theme. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change position of Drupal ajax progress throbber](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89529/change-position-of-drupal-ajax-progress-throbber)

Comment: This is a CSS issue. The input field is too high; original throbber icon combines the default state and loading state on one image, meaning you will either have to edit that gif or use another one with separate images / greater space between them.